# SSRS Reports Should Hide Column "No Output" not working

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, hidden-field

I have a report in SSRS that has subtotals. When a user exports the report to CSV format, they should not be able to see these subtotal columns.

I know this question has been asked before, but the solution to go to Data element output and select no output is not working.

I have also tried to hide the column using an expression. Those are the only two options that I can think of. Does anyone here know exactly what I am doing wrong?